# Connection to a webapp running on AWS being refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a webapp that I run on port 8000. So i start it with the command:

```
> smtweb 
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 12, 2017 - 11:25:27
Django version 1.8.18, using settings None
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Then I try to access the webapp as follows through the public elastic IP that I've associated with the running instance:

```
http://34.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/
```

(I've omitted parts of the IP for my own safety, through XXX)

However, Chrome throws the following error:

```
34.XXX.XXX.XXX refused the connection.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So the connection is refused, even tough I've associated the machine with a security group that has the following rule:

```
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 8000
Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Now, I'm not sure if I have to configure something more in the AWS Tools. It seems that I've done everything there. What I'm asking myself is:

- Does the app have some restrictions by itself?
- I have an Ubuntu image: Do I have to adjust some more firewall settings there?

Do you have an idea what I could try next?

Comment: Your question is not fitting StackOverflow profile. You should try linux.stackexchange.com instead or askubuntu.com

Comment: Your app is bound to 127.0.0.1. It doesn't listen on other network interfaces.

Comment: @Sergey Kovalev: Where would you change this?

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski: I'm not sure yet that it's an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: but definitely it's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means that there is no port open and NOT that the port is blocked by a security group rule. The TCP/IP stack has rejected the connection request.

Double check that you really have port 8000 configured for the interface that you are assigning the EIP.

Try to access your app from the same machine using the destination IP of both the local IP address and EIP.

If the local IP works and the EIP does not, check your network configuration. Your web app might not be binding to the interface assigned to the EIP and might still be configured for the old public IP address or not configured at all.

If both IP addresses work, then the problem is most likely not with your web application. Look at iprules, firewalls, etc. running on your local machine.

Comment: It has nothing to do with EIP. See my comment to the original question.

Comment: Sergey, When I published my answer your post was not there yet (I took a few minutes to answer). I covered the possibility that you mentioned in my response. However, lots of applications only list the first network interface that they bind to and not all interfaces that they bind to, so double checking interface bindings is one of the steps to help solve this issue.